# Modeling Problem (Persian Helmet)

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, sculpting, geometry

I want to model a Helmet, and I am attaching a photo so you can see what it looks like.

[image]

I wanted to know what method you would use to model if you were in my place?

And the second question, is it possible to model with geometry nodes? If yes, how I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. "Modeling problem" does not say much about the content of the question. A title like that fits all modelling questions on BSE and is useless. You should use descriptive titles. "How to model helmet of Cyrus the Great?" or something like that would communicate more.

Comment: This task is definitely not something you should try to solve with Geometry Nodes.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys You are right, thank you for your opinion

Comment: @quellenform Thanks buddy

Comment: @Maxendeer if you agree with Martynas Žiemys, why don't you [change the title](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/304058/edit) and improve your question for readers in the future?

Comment: @Blunder  it just got fixed

Answer (score 5):

Begin with a *UV Sphere* that you cut off (make it match more with your reference image):

[image]

[image]

Extrude behind:

[image]

Extrude along normals to give it thickness:

[image]

Select all these edges and bevel:

[image]

Extrude these top faces along normals, first with a small *Offset*, then a second time with a larger:

[image]

Result with a *Shade Smooth* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help buddy...

But I think you mean is start with cylinder, not uv sphere, right?

Comment: @Maxendeer no it's a UV Sphere, see my edit

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed the first answer, just wanted to include a direction for the remaining parts.

Yes! A UV sphere is the best way to approach the big round part.
No Geometry Nodes are needed for this model.
Similar but slightly different approach is to use Inset on the face strips instead of Extrude

The front part can be modeled using Curve with Bevel Object, a Circle for the disk and star part and subdivided cubes for the two plates.

[image]

**How to inset Face strips**:

Select the odd columns of strips:

[image]

press **"I"** on your keyboard to invoke the Inset operator. Adjust the operator settings and add a Depth in negative direction:

[image]

Select the even columns of face strips:

[image]

Press **Shift+R** to repeat the last operation with the same settings:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the Crown curve and the applied profile curve:

[image]

This is not a tutorial how to model a helmet but a guide on how to approach it.

Here is a .blend file with the model shown in the screenshots above.

[image]

Comment: Good addition! I would have used _Inset_ as well. I would only guess for beginners it is showing way to few steps to get from the beginning to the finished result. But probably he could ask a new question when he's struggling with the parts after modelling the main sphere part.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann. It is really hard to tell if the ridges are sharper or rounder so I went with the Inset option. There are many ways to skin this cat but I can understand the main struggle is how to start the big round shape (i.e  a good starting topology) even for an experienced modeler. Nowadays Geometry Nodes are overused for modeling when Blender can get things done quickly and painlessly with simpler tools. Maxendeer didn't mentioned he is a beginner, so I hope he understood the tips.

Comment: No, he didn't say he's a beginner, you're right. Maybe it's just because from my personal experience that in the beginning here I expected too much understanding/basic knowledge from askers which then turned out to be false. And since the goal of this site is to make questions and answers valuable for other people with similar problems in the future as well, I sometimes tend to be overexplaining things... well, as I also said, if he's struggling with something he can later ask more questions if necessary.

Comment: By the way, yes it is really hard to tell - after I saw the image I asked Google image search for "Persian helmet", but nothing that showed up looked anything like the reference... so I might be missing a special name for this variant. Anyway, I could not find out how it is supposed to be.

Comment: I've found this larger version of the reference image: https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/849916.jpg

Comment: @RumenBelev Amazing result...Thank you so much for your help 

I understood your explanation exactly, but it shows the final result very briefly in the gif photo
I have two problems now, one I can't make the shape used for the curve (bevel circle).
And secondly, can you tell me exactly how you made those bumps on the surface of helmet with inset or whatever !?

Comment: @RumenBelev Can I have your blender file please ?

Comment: Hi @Maxendeer I've updated the answer and included the .blend file for studying. Let us know how your project goes. Cheers.

Comment: Hi bro @RumenBelev I really don't know how to thank you...you did a great favor and help...I checked the file and saw the new photos you posted, now I got exactly what I wanted, your method was so great, thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi @Maxendeer, I am happy to help. Good luck and stay curious ;)